# Convert a series of number become one single line of numbers

Tags: python, pandas, series

If I have a series of numbers in a `DataFrame` with one column, e.g.:

```
import pandas as pd

data = [4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]
pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Which looks like this (left column = index, right column = data):

```
0  4
1  5
2  6
3  7 
4  8
5  9
6  10
7  11
```

How do I make it into one sequence number, so (4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11) in python or pandas ?
because i want to put that into xml file so it looks like this

```
  <Or>
   <numbers>
     <example>4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11</example>
   </numbers>
  </Or>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a f-string with conversion of the integers to string and [`str.join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join):

```
text = f'''  <Or>
   <numbers>
     <example>{" ".join(s.astype(str))}</example>
   </numbers>
  </Or>'''
```

Output:

```
  <Or>
   <numbers>
     <example>4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11</example>
   </numbers>
  </Or>
```

Comment: thanks, what a stupid question I asked, I done the research already but surprised the answer is using 'join'. thanks. I learn

Comment: @beginner you can also use `s.astype(str).str.cat(sep=' ')` if you prefer ;)

Answer (score 1):

use `tolist()` to convert the column value to list and then you can join the list with `str(...)`

```
marks_list = (df['Marks'].tolist())
  
marks_str = (' '.join(str(x) for x in marks_list))
```